# Spring - how do I get the page to refresh after a form is submitted?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Using spring boot, I have a timetable page.

[image]

You can click a square, which opens up a small form with which you can add or remove the class objects from the timetable (which are saved in a database).

My issue is, when you click 'add' (or remove), while it successfully adds/removes that object from the timetable, you have to refresh the page in order to see the class be added/removed on the timetable. It appears like nothing happens when add is clicked from the user's perspective (until they manually refresh the page).

The post method redirects back to the timetable page get. I tried having it redirect to another mini get method, which then redirected back to the original timetable page; but from the browser side it still didn't look like anything was happening - just remaining on the same page with the original problem. Would love to hear a potential solution, thanks!

Edit: Here's an example of my get and post methods:

```
@GetMapping("/timetable/{id}/{semId}")//This method displays timetable.
public String timetable(@PathVariable(value = "id") String id, Model model,
        @PathVariable(value = "semId") String semId) {

//code..
    model.addAttribute("x", x);

    return "timetable";

}

@PostMapping("/timetable/{id}/{semId}")
    public String timetablePost(@ModelAttribute TimetableClassDto dto, @PathVariable(value = "id") String id,
            Model model, @PathVariable(value = "semId") String semId) {
//code..

    return "redirect://timetable/00/" + semId;

}
```

Comment: How do you bind your data ? You're using Spring MVC ? or any MVVM framework ?

Comment: Im using spring-boot, i think thats like Spring MVC ...  I can show you a post method if that would clarify?

Comment: Yes Spring Boot can use MVC, or not :) I mean how to you bind your data to the UI (how you link application logic and layouts). Which front end (i.e. Angular, ZK, etc.) or templating (i.e. thymeleaf, etc.) framework do you use ? Yes show us some code.

Comment: Yes I use thyme leaf in html templates. I'll edit in an example of get and post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you supposed to have two // in your redirect? I have something similar in my code and it works fine. However, I create a url first then return that. Also, make sure your get mapping is properly filling out the object based on the new parameters gotten from the redirect.
Use the following:

```
                       ??
String url = "redirect://timetable/00/" + semId;

return url;
```

Comment: To be honest im not sure why, but this indeed fixed it. Thank you!